# Node.js setTimeout with callbacks

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js

I'm running a node.js app and have a process that runs every 500ms.  There's a lot of logic that's being done and at times, we found it could run over 500ms - this caused problems when using a setInterval.

We redesigned this to use setTimeout with a callback such as this:

```
    var start = function() {

            self.performProcesses(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    start();
                }, 500);
            });
        }

    start();
```

The problem is sometimes this stops, meaning somewhere along the road a callback from `performProcesses` is not being hit.  There are thousands of lines of code that reach multiple objects and files.

Would anyone recommend a good way to try to debug this and isolate where the break may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I program in JavaScript I use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/). It is part of a collection called Appcelerator, which is pretty much Eclipse. Aptana let's you develop and debug in JavaScript, so you can StepInto, StepOver, and whatever..

Comment: JScript !== JavaScript. JScript is microsoft's ripoff of JavaScript. A project where they initially reversed engineered javascript before it was standardized as ECMAScript. Even now, after all these years, there are difference. Anyway, V8 is for javascript. It doesn't support a lot of the extra crap MS put in JScript.

Comment: @MicronXD - Sorry, I meant for JScript to be JavaScript... Aptana doesn't even supprt JScript anyway, so.. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [web-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/)?

You can also try [Paul Irish anim shim](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) at loop controlling. If you call `requestAnimFrame` after `self.performProcess`, it will be called at interval of 500ms.

```
var requestAnimFrame = function (callback) { setTimeout(callback, 500); };

(function animloop () {
  self.performProcesses();
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
})();
```